# Can't read filenames in save dialog box. Names are too faint

Tags: mojave, dialog

I want to click on file to inherit the name for the file being saved. I can't read file names in the dialog box because the color is too faint.
This is the same question as [File Save dialog unreadable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359081/file-save-dialog-unreadable)

That question does not have an answer but I don't have enough points to interact there so I have to post a new question.

[image: Ticking the 'Increase Contrast' checkbox does not help][image: changing the contrast slider does not help]

Edited to add screen shots
I tried to calibrate the monitor which no effect and did not change the readability of "unavailable" file names. I have added screenshots of previous operating systems to compare:
Please tell me how Mojave is not to blame here:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What app are you using? Can the app in question save the file in the format the fainted files are in?

Comment: @Tetsujin Even the OP writes that it's the same question

Comment: See comment below and updated question.

Comment: @Tetsujin Fine for me :-)

Comment: OP, do you have a disability that makes reading low-contrast type particularly difficult or impossible? (Fine if you do, of course—you’d think with Apple’s commitment to accessibility, there would be a way to account for this—I’m just confused, since I can read the hidden files in those screenshots fine.)

Comment: II am legally blind in one eye after a fungal infection 5 years ago severely damaged the retina of my dominant eye so maybe I do. In the three screenshots I posted I have to lean in to distinguish the light grey text in Mojave.  Mountain Lion, and Snow Leopard are easy to read. I agree, Apple is usually helpful in areas of accessibility which made me think there might be an easy fix I overlooked.

Comment: So you are diagnosing my good eye? (and you came back after saying you were gone because of my 'entitlement') I did not ask a question about my eyesight, I asked a question about the difference in the three screenshots above and your answer did not address those differences. Instead you gave an answer about my perception and your comments (also deleted by you) continued to emphasize that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Please stop. You just said I have a special need, that is a diagnosis. You are trying to put the blame on me and I don't know why. I did not say anything was wrong with the good eye. You deleted your answer and are still hanging around to defend it?

Comment: You posted: "you have a special need which you did not bother to include." That is a diagnosis of condition you know nothing about and an assumption that one eye is not as good as two. Your string of comments trying to label me as entitled is quite obvious and the constant scolding by you has done nothing to further the discourse of this thread.

Comment: Your are still here? My use of the word perception (that you quoted) was in response to someone else using that word which has now been deleted. (They were referring to not understanding why the files were a light grey in the first place.) It's been to long for me to remember how that comment ended up directly under your answer but it has apparently triggered you enough to waste your time trying to label me as having an attitude. Perhaps you are one of the users that this blog (and comments) are referring to. https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/

Comment: I had an eye check recently, and the optician said I didn't need glasses. However, even I think I'm straining my eyes reading that faded out text. I have no fixes for you though, sorry :-). Here is the view on macOS 11 (Big Sur) https://i.imgur.com/9m73iAn.png

Answer (score -2):

The save dialog box will gray out files with extensions that differ from the file you're saving. The folders are not grayed out because you are allowed to change folders if you were to choose saving in them.

For example, if you had a folder full of `.docx` and `.xlsx` files while trying to save a `.docx` file all of the `.xlsx` files will be grayed out, but the `.docx` files will be their normal contrast.

Depending on the application, there may be a "File Extension" or a "Format" option at the bottom of the save dialog box where you can save as a different extension. In some cases (although becoming less common) this dialog box may have the option `*.*` that will allow you to select any extension. You've cropped out that part of your screenshots so I can't say exactly if this option exists in your case.

Comment: That is not the issue here. We know why the files are greyed out. The issue is that we cannot read the greyed files in modern macOS whilst we could in older versions.

Comment: You can't. Plain and simple. The only thing you can do is change why the folders are greyed out in the first place. There isn't any preference that allow you to change individual colors, only themes like light and dark mode, or color blind settings in accessibility.

Comment: They are greyed out correctly - how do colour blind settings change what is seen?

Comment: They won't. What you're asking is completely impossible. The options I listed are the only things that even come close to what you want.