# Hidden filenames are too faint to read in Finder

Tags: finder, font, color

I have enabled the display of hidden files in Finder. But the font color looks too faint to me to read.

How can I make the font color darker?

[image: Screen shot of Finder window]

[image: photograph of monitor displaying Finder window]

So this question is now closed because there is a similar question with an answer. That answer did not solve my problem and I don't have enough points (125) to downvote it. I am also confused by the instructions that say "If this question doesn't resolve your question ask a new one", which I did, only to have the new question closed.
[image: Closed]

Comment: IMO The easiest way to see those entries better is to just highlight them.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for reminding me to change the dupe linkage on the other two questions :-)

Comment: The answer by @Tetsujin does not work for me, I still have text in the finder that is to light in color to read.

Comment: Here are some choices: 1. Selected hidden _files/folders_ in **Finder** are easier to read then when not selected. 2. Use **Terminal** as there is no difference in the color of hidden _files/folders_ and regular _files/folders_. 3. Maybe use a third-party file manager.

Comment: @ user3439894. Too bad there is no way to fix for it in the Finder. I rely on those 'hidden' light colored filenames for saving new files by clicking on them to inherit the name and make a slight name change to keep track of versioning. Finding the file to click is difficult.

Comment: @nohillside. Can this question be reopened since the answer was deleted in the similar question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392183/cant-read-filenames-in-save-dialog-box-names-are-too-faint

Comment: Richard Rasch, What if you invoke **Zoom** in **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** so you can toggle  e.g. **⌥⌘8** while in the **Save As** _sheet_. With it zoomed, I would think it's much easier to see.

Comment: @ user3439894 Did not think of zoom. It does help when reading the faint text!

Comment: The other question has no deleted answer, not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: @nohillside You missed the drama. He deleted it in a huff about an hour ago and then reposted it.

Comment: I‘ve seen your edit. Yours is the third question asking the same thing, having separate Q&A won‘t help. The better way would be to add details to the original question or to set a bounty. I agree that the wording in the notice is unfortunate though.

Comment: Asking a different question should be done if your problem is different. If the other question just did not get good enough answers, the recommended way is to set a bounty, which of course you cannot do yet. Unfortunately, I think that the reason that the other question does not an answer that says how to make the text darker is because it's not possible.

Comment: Please do what you can to change the wording. The new user experience here is frustrating when you don't have the privileges to use certain tools and the instructions are not accurate. It also does not help when the only answer posted among the three questions is deleted and reposted as a power play to stroke that user's ego.